# Getting formatted string in Oracle Sql query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, string-formatting

my query is something like this

```
Select date_value from Tab1;
```

The output looks like this (date_value is a Varchar2 column)

```
 2008-2009
 2009-2010
 2007-2009
```

I am trying to some formatting on the column date_value,so that the output looks like this

```
 2008-09
 2009-10
 2007-09
```

Is there a way to do this as part of the above query using some Split/Join inbuilt oracle functions. I was exploring about Instr and Substr, but i am not sure how to do this jsut in that query.

Comment: @cularis has the answer, but keep in mind, this is not a normal way to store data.  If you had two columns -- ex: begin_year, and end_year, then you'd be able to perform date functions, etc.  And of course, you'd still be able to output the 'YYYY-YY' format whenever you wanted to.

Comment: ya i understand what you are saying. since i am running my query on some existing database, don really have much option to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this on a 10g database you can use [Regular Expressions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).

```
SQL> select dcol
  2         , regexp_replace(dcol
  3                          , '([[:digit:]]+)\-([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})'
  4                          , '\1-\3') as regexp_replace
  5  from t79
  6  /

DCOL                           REGEXP_REPLACE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
2008-2009                      2008-09
2009-2010                      2009-10
2007-2009                      2007-09

SQL>
```

Of course, [the usual caveat about regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) applies here, although it does have one distinct advantage: Y10K compliance :)

```
SQL> select dcol
  2         , regexp_replace(dcol
  3                          , '([[:digit:]]+)\-([[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]{2})'
  4                          , '\1-\3') as regexp_replace
  5  from t79
  6  /

DCOL                           REGEXP_REPLACE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
2008-2009                      2008-09
2009-2010                      2009-10
2007-2009                      2007-09
10199-10200                    10199-00
887-888                        887-88

SQL>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(date_value,1,5) || SUBSTR(date_value,8,2) FROM tab1
```

This should work for the next ~8000 years.